# Which permissions does a folder need to Git Clone into it?

Tags: permissions, git

I'm trying to git clone a project onto my Ubuntu server. Yet I get a permission denied error.

If I create a new folder with 777 permissions it works.

What permission level should a folder have to use git clone into it? Or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: `0700` perms on the directory should be sufficient. All you need is write permissions. `0777` is almost *always* unnecessary and a bad idea. FYI, a directory is a path to a physical location in a filesystem. A folder is a logical concept that may or may not map to one or more directories. Linux has directories, not folders.

Comment: @doneal24 this still states permissions denied

Comment: As far as I know, on a home desktop, 755 is the recommended default for dirs. I don't know if that's still recommended for a server. Also, it is important to know, on behalf of which user git is being run. So instead of the git clone, run `whoami` and figure out why that user may have less privileges than expected.

Comment: @Levente that did not work.

Comment: I am assuming that you own the directory. Try `mkdir foo; cd foo; git clone ...`.

Comment: @doneal24 this does not work either. It appears I do not own the directory. How to resolve?

Comment: who is supposed to own the directory? Is it a system directory? if so, you shouldn't be cloning into it and *definitely* don't change permissions or ownership. If it *should* belong to you, you can use `chown` to change directory ownership.

Comment: One requires `w`rite access to a directory to create files/directories in that directory. `ls -ld the_directory;id` will provide more information. The traditional way is to `git clone` into a directory you own (and can write), read the `README.md` file, and follow the instructions.

Comment: Ah, so did you try to clone into `/var/www/` or something?